# Слово "брыла"

Tags: литература, лексика

Просматривал книгу и уже в начале её встретил слово "**брыла**". Употребляется ли оно в русском языке?

В украинском *брыла* (пишется *брила*) -- это *глыба*, большой массивный камень. Разве в русском языке слово "брыла" используется в таком смысле? В словаре Даля я нашёл только, что "брыла" -- это диалектное "губа".

Книга написана на русском. "Часодеи. Часовой ключ", автор Наталья Щерба. Фантастика. Слышал об этой книге неплохие отзывы. Начал просматривать и вот сразу же задумался...

Цитаты:

Уродливой и страшной казалась высокая брыла — жуткий обломок камня, торчащий посреди темного леса.

Он не сводил глаз с трещины, рассекавшей брылу до самого верха, и словно ждал, что камень не выдержит и расколется надвое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стоит по одному автору делать вывод о значении слова в языке.
Вообще в русском - "брылы" губы, особенно - отвисшие, у собак.
Иногда это значение преносится на щёки, это значение считается разговорным.

В ваших цитатах автор явно использует "украинское" значение.

Comment: Спасибо. Ответ для меня исчерпывающий. Пожалуй, его и приму. Это именно то, что я и хотел узнать.
Значит, в России слово "брыла" не используется в значении "большой камень". +1 Вам, и **Marina-ja** тоже +1 поставлю - она ещё раньше ответила.

Comment: >слово "брыла" не используется в значении "большой камень".   

Его нет в общелитературных словарях в подобном значении. А что касается "не используется" - надо на юге копнуть, на Кубани особенно. Если слово общеукраинское (не чичто западеское), то наверняка на Кубань занесло.

Comment: Слово "брЫла" используется не только на Западе Украины, но и в Центре. 

А на Кубани, пожалуй, **большинство** народа -- потомки переселенцев из Центральной Украины, Приднепровья. Даже по названиям станиц можно видеть. И манера говорить у них очень похожа на то, как по-русски говорит житель именно Центральной Украины, а не, скажем, Галичины. 

Так что, соглашусь, на Кубани -- вполне возможно!

Ну и так, уточнение, чтобы уж полностью разобраться с вопросом. По-украински ударение "брЫла", а по-русски как? Так же или на последний слог? *БрЫлы*, *брЫлья* ?

Comment: Нет, если про губы, то на последний. БрылЫ, ед. брылА. Это несколько снижает доверие к версии, что это одно и тоже слово, может и случайное совпадение.   
Впрочем, я по словарю сужу, не могу сказать, что у меня это слово в активном употреблении. Может, где-то в местных говорах и на первый слог уларение ставят.
  
>А на Кубани, пожалуй, большинство народа --  

Я именно об этом. Русская колонизация Кубани шла с Малоросии через Крым. Кубанский казачий диалект очень близок к южноукраинскому суржику. Чем и отличается от донского, который гораздо ближе к центральнорусскому.

Answer (score 1):

Знаю это слово, даже иногда употребляю (правда, немного в другой форме — брылы и брылья), в значении "отвислые губы, щеки, подбородок". 
[link text](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E1%F0%FB%EB%FB&all=x)

Comment: А я читала "брыли". Но это совсем не тот смысл, который употреблен в цитатах. В _этом_ смысле слово незнакомое.

Comment: Смысл здесь — нечто выпирающее, неважно что )

Answer (score 1):

Да, есть такое слово в украинском, обозначает массивный камень. Думаю, автор использовал его для создания карпатского колорита. Скажем, Гоголь не гнушался использовать украинские слова в русском языке, ту же "панночку" или "красную свитку"
Книгу читала, очень хорошая сказка для детей.

Comment: А там точно карпатский колорит? Тогда и думать нечего.

Да нет, чот непохоже... там типичное фэнтези, вне реального мира.

Comment: Автор точно с "украинскими" корнями. Или в детстве лето у бабушки "там" проводил.  Явно не северный "выговор" )

Comment: Откуда такой вывод?  
Да, собсно, я такого не исключаю, но одно дело - у бабушки, другое - в тексте.

Comment: Посмотрел в Википедии. Эта писательница родилась в Белоруссии, сейчас гражданка Украины. Но... **Marina-ja**, что ещё, кроме украинского употребления слова "брыла", можно увидеть нероссийского в этих двух цитатах? Просто любопытно стало!

**Латышева**, Вы прочитали эту книгу, разве там идёт речь об Украине?

Я вчера написал этот вопрос на форум уже вечером, и книгу начал просматривать тогда же. Дальше начАла не продвинулся.

Comment: Я ничего "нероссийского" не вижу.

Comment: Да, я прочитала все три книги - замечательная сказочная фантастика. Автор не делает акцент ни на времени повествования, ни на месте действия (для сказки это хорошо, на мой взгляд), и в то же время при описании природы (горы, буковые леса, поросль ежевики, чабрец и мята) чувствуется именно карпатский колорит. В первой книге действие происходит в часовом мире, а во второй часовщики попадают в обычный детский лагерь. Там есть фигурные скалы, походы в лес, битвы шишками, чай с гнилушкой и прочие детские радости.

Comment: Честно говоря, очень хорошие книги, я советую прочитать. Первая книга очень неровная по стилю - видно, что автор только пробует перо, но с каждой книгой мастерств орастёт в геометрическом порядке.

Comment: **Латышева**, большое спасибо за подробный ответ. От меня +1 в репутацию. 

Сейчас хорошие книги и фильмы (из новых) выбираешь, как иголку в стоге сена. Мало их. Поэтому прислушиваюсь к рекомендациям.

:-) В буковые леса на Западе Украины интересно было бы попасть *в реальности*, а не сказке. Видел их по ТВ -- красота! Называли их необыкновенным словом. Если попробовать написать по-русски, то *прАлесы* (букові праліси). Сразу представляешь себе нетронутый с давних-давних (прадавних :) ) пор сказочный лес.

Comment: Ездил я как-то в Холодный Яр. Это Украина, Черкасская область, район Чигирина. Там ещё церковь Б.Хмельницкого, которая на 5 гривнах изображена, находится. Какой лес! Ощущение сказки! Дуб, которому больше тысячи лет. Ладно, отклоняюсь от темы. Я об этом и больше написать мог бы -- нравится :-)

Comment: @Латышева, сильно подозреваю, что качества этой детской книги оценят скорее взрослые. У нынешних детей другой мир и другие радости. Сужу по своему сыну и его одноклассникам.

Comment: Nikolja, спасибо. Я бывала в Карпатах несколько раз, мне очень понравилось. Действительно, сказочные места, красивая, дикая природа. Правда, я не поднималась далеко в горы, мы с семьёй жили в домике на курорте Буковель.

Comment: Docentl, Часодеи невероятно популярны среди детей. Моя дочь состоит в группе поклонников, их там четыре тысячи! Помню, что очень удивилась, - всё-таки отечественная книга нового автора и так популярна. Раньше мне казалось, что большинство современных детей сначала смотрят фильм, а потом читают книгу - и только в этом случае книга будет иметь популярность, как тот же Гарри Поттер, скажем.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно породы собак с такими отвисшими губами называют брылястыми.
То, что слово *брыли* ещё употребляется я и не знал.

Comment: Отчасти оно еше в ходу. Только в этом значении - брылЫ. 
Знаете, где я его слышал? От собачьих заводчиков. При описании экстерьера. Сам я не собачник ни разу, но сталкиваться приходилось.

Answer (score 0):

"Брыла" (по-польски "bryla") в переводе на русский значит "глыба". По-украински будет "брила".